# How to show values on top of bars in a PDF using chart.js and chartjs-node-canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, canvas, chart.js

I need to show the values on the top of bars using [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) to create a PDF in Node

I have been able to recreate what I am looking in HTML but the plugin has the limitation of not accepting the "animation" property, for this reason I am looking to know if there is another way to do it in Node without the need for another external plugin. [This is my current code](https://codepen.io/fjalcode/pen/ZEKWOOy)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 1,
        label: "promedio",
        order: 1,
        data: [60, 49, 72, 90, 100, 60]
      },
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        borderColor: "orange",
        borderWidth: 1,
        label: "promedio",
        order: 1,
        data: [40, 5, 20, 30, 10, 6]
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        label: "casos",
        data: [25, 13, 30, 35, 25, 40],
        lineTension: 0,
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderColor: "red",
        order: 0,
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        },
        animation: {
          duration: 1,
          onComplete: function () {
            var chartInstance = this.chart,
              ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(16, 20, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
              var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
              meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                var data = dataset.data[index];
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 2);
              });
            });
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, you either have to implement your own external inline plugin or use the datalabels plugin (https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html) since there is no build in way to achieve this

Comment: I am trying to implement your advice but I have not succeeded yet, can you tell me if you see what the error would be?, [I created a new post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306594/how-could-i-implement-chartjs-plugin-datalabels-in-chartjs-node-canvas)